# Execute Payment - PayPal REST API

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

The PayPal REST ExpressCheckout API has two parts:
Authenticate and Execute.
All goes well with authentication but execution fails.

I am following this sample code: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/ExecutePayment.html

I don't really understand the process. It tries to GET some parameters that do not exist in my URL. And when do I use the return URLs?

Here is my HTML:

```
{% extends 'layout/master.twig' %}

{% block title %} {{ parent() }}PayPal {% endblock title %}

{% block head %}
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block header %} Testing PayPal {% endblock header %}


{% block content %}

    <div id="paypal-button"></div>

{% endblock content %}


{% block scripts %}
    <script>
        paypal.Button.render({

            env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'production' environment

            payment: function (resolve, reject) {

                var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = 'http://patch-request.app/paypal/payment/create';

                paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL)
                    .then(function (data) {
                        resolve(data.id);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    });
            },

            onAuthorize: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                // Note: you can display a confirmation page before executing

                var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'http://patch-request.app/paypal/payment/execute';

                paypal.request.post
                    (
                    EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL,
                        {
                            paymentID: data.paymentID,
                            payerID: data.payerID
                        }
                    )
                    .then(function (data) {
                        /* Go to a success page */
                        console.log('SUCCESS!!!!!!!!!');
                        console.log(data);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        /* Go to an error page  */
                        console.log('ERROR!!!!!!!!!');
                        console.log(data);
                    });
            }

        }, '#paypal-button');
    </script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

Here is the authentication part of the PHP:

```
    /**
     * Initialize a payment that needs to be verified
     *
     * @return JSON paymentID
     */
    public function authorize_payment ()
    {
        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

        $item1 = new Item();
        $item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setSku("123123")// Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
            ->setPrice(7.5);
        $item2 = new Item();
        $item2->setName('Granola bars')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(5)
            ->setSku("321321")// Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
            ->setPrice(2);

        $itemList = new ItemList();
        $itemList->setItems([$item1, $item2]);

        $details = new Details();
        $details->setShipping(1.2)
            ->setTax(1.3)
            ->setSubtotal(17.50);

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency("USD")
            ->setTotal(20)
            ->setDetails($details);

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription("Payment description")
            ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

//        $baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
        $baseUrl = "http://patch-request.app";
        $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/blog")
            ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/blog/cleardb");

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent("sale")
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
            ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

        $request = clone $payment;

        try
        {
            $payment->create($this->apiContext); //$payment is a JSON
        }
        catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            echo 'Sth went wrong';
        }

        $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
//        d($approvalUrl);

//        ResultPrinter::printResult("Created Payment Using PayPal. Please visit the URL to Approve.", "Payment",
//            "<a href='$approvalUrl' >$approvalUrl</a>", $request, $payment);

//        return json_encode(['paymentID' => $payment->id]);
        return $payment;
    }
```

and here is the execution part of the PHP that fails:

```
    /**
     * Execute the authorized payment
     */
    public function execute_payment ()
    {
        ChromePhp::log('outside');
        ChromePhp::log($_GET);

//        if (isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == 'true')
//        {
            ChromePhp::log('inside');
            $paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
            $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $this->apiContext);

            $execution = new PaymentExecution();
            $execution->setPayerId($_GET['PayerID']);

            $transaction = new Transaction();
            $amount = new Amount();
            $details = new Details();

            $details->setShipping(2.2)
                ->setTax(1.3)
                ->setSubtotal(17.50);

            $amount->setCurrency('USD');
            $amount->setTotal(21);
            $amount->setDetails($details);
            $transaction->setAmount($amount);

            $execution->addTransaction($transaction);

            try
            {
                $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->apiContext);
                ChromePhp::log($result);

                try
                {
                    // Could not get payment
                    $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $this->apiContext);
                    ChromePhp::log($payment);
                }
                catch (Exception $ex)
                {
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $ex)
            {
                // Could not execute payment
                exit(1);
            }

            return $payment;
//        }
//        else
//        {
             //User cancelled the approval
//            exit;
//        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on their site is quite horrid. The example Javascript they give you sends those two variables in a **POST** request, and the PHP-SDK example looks for a **GET** request. They're just asking for people to run into problems.

You can see the below snippet sends both `paymentID` and the `payerID` in a POST request.

```
onAuthorize: function (data) {
console.log(data);
// Note: you can display a confirmation page before executing

var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'http://patch-request.app/paypal/payment/execute';

paypal.request.post
    (
    EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL,
        {
            paymentID: data.paymentID,  // this object is sent with the above URL
            payerID: data.payerID .     // as a payload with the POST request
        }
    )
    .then(function (data) {
        /* Go to a success page */
        console.log('SUCCESS!!!!!!!!!');
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        /* Go to an error page  */
        console.log('ERROR!!!!!!!!!');
        console.log(data);
    });
```

}

Try adapting any references to this in the PHP examples to `$_POST` as below:

```
$paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
```

to:

```
$paymentId = $_POST['paymentId'];
```

Comment: yes you are right. The problem is that some of their sample code refers to the pop-up/javascript way of doing things (without being redirected to their site) and the rest of the code refers to the method with redirections. As you said, it needs some tinkering in order to work. I will share here later my final version to serve as a reference.